# VisualStudio , Convert Selected Codes To Existing Method

Tags: visual-studio

I want to convert my selected codes to a one line code. 
To get more info check out this example :

myCode :

```
write("test_1");
say("test_2");
playSound(true);
```

Convert it to :

```
Message("test_1","test_2",true);
```

** I wrote this method to write this code easier but its very hard to replace all type of this code to this method **

Is there any option that  `VisualStudio` do this or i need plugin or ...?

Comment: You can use the extract method functionality, select the 3 lines of code right click and choose `quick actions ->extract method` or `Refactoring -> extract method` depending on your version of visual studio.

Comment: You don't mention whcih version of VS you're using. ReSharper can do the same thing for earlier versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: I have VS2015, oh ok i will check it out